# gridster add widget on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, gridster

I'm evaluating gridster jquery plugin for customizing a dashboard and it  seems perfect for my needs. But there's something i can't get working. I want to add a new widget dynamically when an 'add button' is clicked, using the add_widget function documented in the library. 
The result is that the widget seems to be added but then disappears and everything rolls back to the initial state.

```
$(function(){
    gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
                widget_base_dimensions: [100, 120],
                widget_margins: [5, 5],
                draggable: {
                    handle: '.dragDiv'
                }
    }).data('gridster');   
    gridster.add_widget.apply(gridster, ['<li>new</li>', 1, 2]);

    $(document).on( "click", "#addWidgetButton", function() { 
       gridster.add_widget.apply(gridster, ['<li>new</li>', 1, 2]);
    });
});
```

Look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H6dCR/).

As you can see in the example I use the same function to add a widget first in the general scope (and it works), and then in the button click event handler but it doesn't work properly.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should disable the default click event of the button.

Right code:

```
$(document).on( "click", "#addWidgetButton", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); 
     gridster.add_widget.apply(gridster, ['<li>new</li>', 1, 2]);
});
```

Comment: any insights on why does this work?  I didn't try it but I don't see why from a separate button you would have to use prevent default.